# Google +1 HTML validation failed to W3C standards

Tags: validation, w3c

I am using Google +1 on my [games website](http://www.daily1game.com/). It's very difficult for me to validate the page. I tried near about every solutions on stackoverflow but always disappointed :-(
Please help me to solve the problem.

Here is the code I'm using,

```
<div class="gbutton" ><g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone></div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For w3c validation please use the code like,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<g:plusone size="medium" href=""></g:plusone>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this guy has an answer:

http://jamesingham.me/blog/google-plusone-w3c-valid

Even though it's not strictly "valid."

Comment: Hello Kyle Boddy, Thanks for the answer I used the javascript code but it's showing an error - there is no attribute "size".

Comment: Then omit it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution which validates the page successfully.

```
<div class="g-plusone"></div>
```

But drawback is we can't use size="medium".